# Compare 2 dates and get the real time value in days PHP Data Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, timestamp

I am trying to achieve the difference between two dates which are entered in PHP. one is the record entry date and one is delivery date. record entry date is saved as follows.

```
    $insertDate=curdate();
    function curdate() {
    // gets current timestamp
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai'); 
      return date('Y-m-d');
    }
```

And the delivery date would be saved as an HTML input.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="deliveryDate">Delivery Date</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" name="deliveryDate" required>                    
</div>
```

both are being saved in the db perfectly, for me to access those in a jquery data table.

[image: dataTable]

now in the D/Left column, I would want to see the the days left to be delivered the particular product. In order to achieve this, what I have done was

> delivery date - record entered date = days left.

```
$deliveryDateToSec = strtotime($deliveryDate);
$insertDateToSec = strtotime($insertDate);
$timeDiff = abs($deliveryDateToSec - $insertDateToSec);
$daysLeft = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
//convert to integer
$daysLeft = intval($daysLeft);
```

although I am able to achieve the task by this way, my requirement is the days left should be realtime. As in if i add a record today - 18-05-2020, the delivery date is - 20-05-2020, then the days left would be 2. And when I see the record tomorrow, it should be 1. Likewise the subtraction has to happen as a something like reducing 1 day per everyday. I was trying to do this in many ways but I couldn't complete this. if there is anyway that this can be done using JQuery Datatable methods, Suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should subtract the current date from the delivery date every time when you show the table.

```php
<?php

$deliveryDateToSec = strtotime($deliveryDate);
$currentDateToSec = strtotime(Date('Y-m-d'));
$timeDiff = $deliveryDateToSec - $currentDateToSec;
$daysLeft = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
//convert to integer
$daysLeft = intval($daysLeft);

if ($daysLeft < 0) {
    $daysLeft = 0;
}

echo $daysLeft;
```

Comment: Yea, Acc to my scenario, insert date is current date. I am able to get the days left that's fine. If i see the record tomorrow on data table, it will still be the old value. It would not be realtime.

Comment: You should get the current date(`strtotime(Date('Y-m-d'))`) and do the calculation every time when you show the table. You can do it in Javascript as well.

Comment: I was finding ways to implement it on JS as well. Since data table is connected, I am getting stuck during the implementation.

Comment: Can you show the PHP/JavaScript code that creates the table?

Comment: Thank you so much man. it was a piece of cake that I was trying to implement in a wrong place.